# HTTP Session Management while using Nginx as in “Round Robin” mode Load-balancer?

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, load-balancing, glusterfs, round-robin

I'm trying to load-balance "2 Web Servers (running Apache/PHP)" by putting nginx in front of them. But **I need to use Round Robin algorithm** but when I do this, **I can't manage to have the stable SESSIONS**.

(I understand; if I use Round Robin, the session information will be lost once I hit to the another server on next load)

Is there a proper way to achieve this? Any kind advice for the industrial standards on this please?

*FYI, I've already put these 2 Web Servers into `GlusterFS` as in Cluster. So I have a common storage (if you are going to suggest something based on this)*

Answer (score 4):

Even though this is an old post it still has high SEO rating thus trying to answer.

While you may take advantage of the clustered storage you should always deal with session persistance in single memory segment.

For your situation the easiest way may be using one of the possible NGINX ways to keep persistent target upstream server. Easiest could still be the [ip_hash](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash) directive as it might well suit your needs.

For business needs I'd recommend ordering commercial subscription and use sticky directive which and as well enjoy many other advantages including extensive support.

Another option is to use some 3rd party (open source) plugin (eg. [nginx-sticky-module-ng](https://bitbucket.org/nginx-goodies/nginx-sticky-module-ng/src)) to create same functionality without need for paying the subscription.

Comment: hi, thanks much for your suggestions. I suspect most of the approaches you advised are for the "sticky" sessions (traffic tied to one server?), if i'm not wrong? I needed "round robin", to hit different Server on each loads. Can i confirm on this please? Thanks :)

Comment: This really depends on the mechanism used in your PHP application - if you want to always hit different server then you'd have to make sure the backend DB/filesystem storing the session data is synced in timely manner - GlusterFS may not be as quick as needed as the communication over SSH connection introduces always some at least minimal delay. If session information is stored within file on this this really won't work well and I'll suggest to either use the sticky version or update the PHP code to use some common storage - possibly in-memory DB rather than disk (Redis etc.).